# Removing negative numbers from NSArray in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am new to Objective C. In my application, I am having array of data, in which I need only positive numbers and need to delete negative numbers.

```
result = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects: @"1",@"2",@"3","-4","-5","6","9",nil];
NSLog(@"  Before Remove  %d", [result count]);
NSString *nullStr = @"-";
[result removeObject:nullStr];
```

How to achieve this? Any pointers?

Comment: Even if your code isn't working, it seems more that you want to use an abs() than removing the negative number...

Comment: You could use an NSPredicate to filter the array down to negative numbers then remove those values.

Comment: Just to be clear, will your array contain NSNumbers, or NSStrings?

Comment: not related, but **please** don't use capitalized names for variables

Comment: The array you are creating... first, it should start with a lower case "r". `result = ...` second, you are populating it with strings not numbers.

Answer (score 6):

You can use a predicate to filter the array

```
NSArray * numbers = @[@"1", @"2", @"3", @"-4", @"-5", @"6", @"9"];
NSPredicate * predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"integerValue >= 0"];
NSArray * positiveNumbers = [numbers filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

Result

```
[@"1", @"2", @"6", @"9"]
```

Also note that this will work with both an array of `NSNumber`s and an array of `NSString`s, since they both feature the `integerValue` method.

Answer (score 2):

the one you wrote is an array of strings, if that's ok you can loop the array and remove strings that starts with - using

Since you cannot remove objects while iterating, you can create a new array and store only positive numbers (or mark item to be deleted and delete after the loop)

```
NSMutableArray onlyPositives = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]
for(int i=0; i < [result count]; i++)
{
    if(![result[i] hasPrefix:@"-"])
        [onlyPositives add:[result[i]]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
for(NSString *number in [result copy])
{
    if([number intValue] < 0)
    {
         [result removeObject:number];
    }
}
```

Comment: It's generally a bad idea to mutate a collection while it is being fast enumerated.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSIndexSet *indexesOfNegativeNumbers = [result indexesOfObjectsPassingTest:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    return [(NSString *)obj hasPrefix:@"-"];
}];

[result removeObjectsAtIndexes:indexesOfNegativeNumbers];
```

Comment: `hasPrefix:` already returns a BOOL. There's not point in using a ternary if.

Comment: @GabrielePetronella Fixed, need coffee :)

Answer (score 0):

If you have an array and you want to filter items out of it, then using an NSPredicate is a good way to do it.

You haven't said whether your array contains NSNumbers or NSStrings, so here's a demonstration of how to use predicates to filter an array in both cases

```
// Setup test arrays
NSArray *stringArray = @[@"-1", @"0", @"1", @"2", @"-3", @"15"];
NSArray *numberArray = @[@(-1), @0, @1, @2, @(-3), @15];

// Create the predicates 
NSPredicate *stringPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"integerValue >= 0"];
NSPredicate *numberPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF >= 0"];

// Filtering the original array returns a new filtered array
NSArray *filteredStringArray = [stringArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:stringPredicate];
NSArray *filteredNumberArray = [numberArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:numberPredicate];

// Just to see the results, lets log the filtered arrays.
NSLog(@"New strings %@", filteredStringArray); // 0, 1, 2, 15
NSLog(@"New strings %@", filteredNumberArray); // 0, 1, 2, 15
```

This should get you started.

Comment: Nice, but `"NOT (SELF BEGINSWITH %@)", @"-"` could be simply `intValue >= 0`

Comment: Yep, thanks and fixed, although I prefer to use integerValue over intValue.

Comment: also there's not need of differentiating the two cases if you use `intValue` or `integerValue`. Check my answer